# Google Map different color for default marker icon depending on SEVERITY in generated XML

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have generated XML(alarms.xml) in format (example)

```
<markers>
 <marker lat="41.932797" lng="21.483765" alarm="Boston" severity="0"   />
 <marker lat="41.732797" lng="21.183765" alarm="Toronto" severity="2"   />
</markers>
```

Depending on severity different color for default marker needs to be showed:

```
0-green
1-violet
2-ocher
```

etc.

What do I have to change in this my simple html file?

Thanks for help

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Google Maps</title>
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;sensor=false&amp;" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>
  <body onunload="GUnload()">

    <table border=1>
      <tr>
        <td>
           <div id="map" style="width: 1550px; height: 1450px"></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>


    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[

    if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {

      var gmarkers = [];


      function createMarker(point,name,alarm) {
        var marker = new GMarker(point);
        GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
          marker.openInfoWindowHtml(alarm);
        });

        return marker;
      }



      function myclick(i) {
        GEvent.trigger(gmarkers[i], "click");
      }


      var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
      map.addControl(new GLargeMapControl());
      map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
      map.setCenter(new GLatLng( 41.932797,21.483765), 10);



      GDownloadUrl("alarms.xml", function(doc) {
        var xmlDoc = GXml.parse(doc);
        var markers = xmlDoc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");

        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          // obtain the attribues of each marker
          var lat = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat"));
          var lng = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng"));
          var point = new GLatLng(lat,lng);
          var alarm = markers[i].getAttribute("alarm");
          var label = markers[i].getAttribute("label");
          // create the marker
          var marker = createMarker(point,label,alarm);
          map.addOverlay(marker);
        }

      });
    }




    //]]>
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you add the marker, set up a custom icon per severity level:

```
var severity = parseInt(markers[i].getAttribute("severity"));
var severityIcon = new GIcon(G_DEFAULT_ICON);
var color;
if (severity == 1) color = "red";
else if (severity == 2) color = "blue";
else if (severity == 3) color = "green";
else color = "yellow";
severityIcon.image = "http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/" + color + "-dot.png";

markerOptions = { icon:severityIcon };
```

Then add it to the map like this:

```
map.addOverlay(new GMarker(latlng, markerOptions));
```

This is taken from the excellent Google Maps examples site here:  https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/examples/icon-simple

Comment: Thanks for answer but I think this does not suite my needs. You only created one differenet color. I think I need some function to do the mapping because I will have in this example 3 different colors. So when I take  severity var severity=markers[i].getAttribute("severity"); I think I need to call some function with parametar Severity which will do the mapping based on the severity.

Comment: That's easily fixed with a conditional statement, no?  (updated in answer above)

Comment: Hi yes I meant exactly on that. Please can you look at my addOverlay function because I think that is the problem why it is not still working to me (you use latlng and I use just marker) 

map.addOverlay(marker,markerOptions);

Comment: It works now I found the errors. THANKS  one more question sorry can I somehow use hexadecimal values instead of the names of the colors? because I have more specific colors like ocher and light blue

Comment: Try this:  var severityIcon = new StyledIcon(StyledIconTypes.BUBBLE,{color:"#ff0000",text:"1"});  (example here: http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmarker/examples/change_color.htm)